# Relationship between mutual information and the sign of the relationship

Tags: computational-statistics, mutual-information, association-measure

Assume we have two variables A and B, and we are trying to find the Mutual Information between them. Can the mutual information enable us to find if there exists a positive or negative relationship between two variables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't statisticians use mutual information as a measure of association?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68035/why-dont-statisticians-use-mutual-information-as-a-measure-of-association)